# How to Check If The Rune is Chinese Punctuation Character in Go

Tags: go, unicode, cjk, punctuation, chinese-locale

For Chinese punctuation chars like `～` `，` `。`, how to detect via Go?

I tried with range table of package `unicode` like the code below, but `Han` doesn't include those punctuation chars.

Can you please tell me which range table should I use for this task? (Please refraining from using `regex` because it's low performance.)

```
for _, r := range strToDetect {
    if unicode.Is(unicode.Han, r) {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/WR2tZa0EliF ?

Comment: @mh-cbon Thanks for your reply! Actually I need more general solution, not just list all the punc chars. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_punctuation

Comment: Seeing how you have exceptions to the character set like`～` (U+FF5E is not punctuation), you are going to need to add an additional check for those not in the list of Chinese punctuation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puctuation marks are scattered about in different Unicode code blocks.

---

> The Unicode® Standard
> Version 14.0 – Core Specification
>
> Chapter 6
> Writing Systems and Punctuation
> https://www.unicode.org/versions/latest/ch06.pdf
>
> Punctuation. The rest of this chapter deals with a special case: punctuation marks, which tend to be scattered about in different blocks and which may be used in common by many scripts. Punctuation characters occur in several widely separated places in the blocks, including Basic Latin, Latin-1 Supplement, General Punctuation, Supplemental Punctuation, and CJK Symbols and Punctuation. There are also occasional punctuation characters in blocks for specific scripts.

---

Here are two of your examples,

〜 Wave Dash U+301C

。Ideographic Full Stop U+3002

---

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unicode"
)

func main() {
    // CJK Symbols and Punctuation Unicode block
    for r := rune('\u3000'); r <= '\u303F'; r++ {
        if unicode.IsPunct(r) {
            fmt.Printf("%[1]U\t%[1]c\n", r)
        }
    }
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/WoJjM6JKTYR

```
U+3001  、
U+3002  。
U+3003  〃
U+3008  〈
U+3009  〉
U+300A  《
U+300B  》
U+300C  「
U+300D  」
U+300E  『
U+300F  』
U+3010  【
U+3011  】
U+3014  〔
U+3015  〕
U+3016  〖
U+3017  〗
U+3018  〘
U+3019  〙
U+301A  〚
U+301B  〛
U+301C  〜
U+301D  〝
U+301E  〞
U+301F  〟
U+3030  〰
U+303D  〽
```